# Are there any open source applications out there using Three20?

Tags: iphone, three20

I was wondering if anyone knows of any open source applications that are using **three20**. Would be very useful to have when I'm having trouble figuring things out.

Comment: What about the Three20 [sample code](https://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/master/samples)?

Comment: I'm looking to see how people use the framework and apply their own techniques for certain task that the sample code doesn't really get into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ran a github search for objective-c projects with has three20 in their description. There are many apps out there on github:

https://github.com/search?langOverride=&language=Objective-C&q=three20&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&x=0&y=0

https://github.com/daveknapik/Touch320

https://github.com/freshblocks/Picasa-App

https://github.com/aporat/three20-splitview-example